# How to do a group by in pandas of N observatios

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with two series.  One a datetime at the minute level and a float.  Assume 1000 observations i.e. 1000 minutes. From the time of the last datetime I need to do a group by sum of the float at 15 minute intervals.  So..this is for doing a rolling group by.  Another minute is added..need to redo the group by of the last 15 mins.

What is the most pythonic method to do this?  E.g if the last observed is 12:17:00 then do a group by from 12:02:00 to 12:17:00

```
...
...
11:46:00 to 12:01:00
12:02:00 to 12:17:00


import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


dt = "2014-05-05 17:01:00"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")
datetime
hash_list = []
for i in xrange(35):
    now = dt + timedelta(minutes=i+1)
    temp = {"date": now, "exr": 1}
    hash_list.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame(hash_list)
df = df.set_index('date')
```

The above will create 35 observation.

sum should look like this regardless of the current minute

```
2014-05-05 17:06:00   5
2014-05-05 17:21:00   15
2014-05-05 17:36:00   15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit unclear to me what you mean with a 'rolling groupby'. To me, rolling suggests that the timespan of the groups overlap, which is not what you show in your example. So whats rolling here?

You can use Pandas Timegrouper to groupby blocks of 15min. If your DataFrame (df) has the timestamp as the index, then use:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15Min', base=df.index[-1].minute)).sum()
```

That will give you the sum for each block of 15 minutes, where the blocks are defined by the last timestamp in the index.

#### edit:

You can change the definition of the blocks with 'closed' and 'label':

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='15Min', base=df.index[-1].minute, closed='right', label='right')).sum()
```

Comment: I exapanded the example with code.  Using for example did not quite work but if you run you will see why

Comment: See my edit, it really comes down to how you specify your 15min blocks, which still isn't completely clear to me.

Comment: Yup...thats what I needed.  Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to group by that. Typically, `groupby()` gives you several groups that are unified by one attribute. However, you just want one group, the one that contains the latest 15 minutes. Those you can find using [truncate()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#truncating-fancy-indexing).